# Custom method names in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm converting from the WCF Web API to the new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API. I have a UsersController, and I want to have a method named Authenticate. I see examples of how to do GetAll, GetOne, Post, and Delete, however what if I want to add extra methods into these services? For instance, my UsersService should have a method called Authenticate where they pass in a username and password, however it doesn't work.

```
public class UsersController : BaseApiController
{
    public string GetAll()
    {
        return "getall!";
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "get 1! " + id;
    }

    public User GetAuthenticate(string userName, string password, string applicationName)
    {
        LogWriter.Write(String.Format("Received authenticate request for username {0} and password {1} and application {2}",
            userName, password, applicationName));

        //check if valid leapfrog login.
        var decodedUsername = userName.Replace("%40", "@");
        var encodedPassword = password.Length > 0 ? Utility.HashString(password) : String.Empty;
        var leapFrogUsers = LeapFrogUserData.FindAll(decodedUsername, encodedPassword);

        if (leapFrogUsers.Count > 0)
        {
            return new User
            {
                Id = (uint)leapFrogUsers[0].Id,
                Guid = leapFrogUsers[0].Guid
            };
        }
        else
            throw new HttpResponseException("Invalid login credentials");
    }
}
```

I can browse to myapi/api/users/ and it will call GetAll and I can browse to myapi/api/users/1 and it will call Get, however if I call myapi/api/users/authenticate?username={0}&password={1} then it will call Get (NOT Authenticate) and error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'Navtrak.Services.WCF.NavtrakAPI.Controllers.UsersController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

How can I call custom method names such as Authenticate?

Comment: Please refer this link: 5th answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40261803#40261803

Answer (score 140, accepted):

By default the route configuration follows RESTFul conventions meaning that it will accept only the Get, Post, Put and Delete action names (look at the route in global.asax => by default it doesn't allow you to specify any action name => it uses the HTTP verb to dispatch). So when you send a GET request to `/api/users/authenticate` you are basically calling the `Get(int id)` action and passing `id=authenticate` which obviously crashes because your Get action expects an integer.

If you want to have different action names than the standard ones you could modify your route definition in `global.asax`:

```
Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now you can navigate to `/api/users/getauthenticate` to authenticate the user.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to still use Get(id), Get() Put, Delete, Post while still allowing other actions?

Comment: @ShawnMclean I guess that you could specify another route without `{action}` that has a constraint on `{id}` so that anything other than `int` or `Guid` (or whatever) wouldn't match.  Then it should be able to fall through to the one suggested by Darin

Comment: One more important thing here is that with this style of routing, you must use attributes to specify the allowed HTTP methods (like [HttpGet]).

Comment: are you sure you need to use other actions? Have you really tried to fit what you are doing within REST conventions? It should not be necessary to use other actions.

Comment: @niico: Imagine you wanted to have a Count() method, that returns the number of elements Get() would return. I don't see how to fit that into Get(), Get(id), Post(...), Put(...) or Delete(id). And, of course, there are indefinately more possible methods I could imagine.

Comment: As for Web Api 2, navigating to `/api/users/getauthenticate` requires an additional step, which other answers for this post demonstrate: Either use Attribute Routing (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62430115/3002584)), or use `HttpGet` + `ActionName` attributes (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62026225/3002584)), or use `HttpGet` + query params (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31564702/3002584)).

Answer (score 89):

This is the best method I have come up with so far to incorporate extra GET methods while supporting the normal REST methods as well.  Add the following routes to your WebApiConfig:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new {action = "Post"}, new {httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post)});
```

I verified this solution with the test class below.  I was able to successfully hit each method in my controller below:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public string GetAll()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

I verified that it supports the following requests:

```
GET /Test
GET /Test/1
GET /Test/GetAll
POST /Test
PUT /Test/1
DELETE /Test/1
```

*Note* That if your extra GET actions do not begin with 'Get' you may want to add an HttpGet attribute to the method.

Comment: nice solution, could you tell me if I configure the `put` and `delete` verbs such as you did on `get` and `post`, will work fine too?

Comment: In my opinion this should be included in the defaults for WebAPI projects (perhaps commented out). It gives you WebAPI AND MVC style routes at the same time...

Comment: @FelipeOriani, I don't think you would want or need to configure `put` or `delete` verbs since those requests would typically accompany an id parameter to identify the resource you wish to apply that operation to.  A `delete` call to `/api/foo` should throw an error because which foo are you trying to delete?  Therefore the DefaultApiWithId route should handle those cases fine.

Comment: this didn't work out for me at all.  got error messages when I tried to do a basic GET.

Comment: For the first one, DefaultApiWithId, shouldn't the defaults be null instead of new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }?  Isn't the 'id' required?

Comment: Just like to point out for those scaffolding the WebAPI2 controllers in Visual studios. The RESTful names are `Get<ControllerName>` instead of just `Get()`, so if you remove `new { action = "Get" }` from the above code snipplet, then you don't have to go changing all your scaffolded classes or modifying the T4 scripts.

Comment: This configuration is evil and it took me a whole day to find out this was the cause for my CORS preflight requests failing.
DO NOT USE THIS if you need CORS support as well, because the first mapping already kills OPTION requests (DefaultApiWithId).

Answer (score 22):

I am days into the MVC4 world.

For what its worth, I have a SitesAPIController, and I needed a custom method, that could be called like:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/SitesAPI/Disposition/0
```

With different values for the last parameter to get record with different dispositions.

What Finally worked for me was:

The method in the SitesAPIController:

```
// GET api/SitesAPI/Disposition/1
[ActionName("Disposition")]
[HttpGet]
public Site Disposition(int disposition)
{
    Site site = db.Sites.Where(s => s.Disposition == disposition).First();
    return site;
}
```

And this in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
// this was already there
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// this i added
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Action",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{disposition}"
 );
```

For as long as I was naming the {disposition} as {id} i was encountering:

```
{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9000/api/SitesAPI/Disposition/0'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'SitesAPI' that matches the request."
}
```

When I renamed it to {disposition} it started working.  So apparently the parameter name is matched with the value in the placeholder.

Feel free to edit this answer to make it more accurate/explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was making the same mistake as you.

Answer (score 16):

Web Api by default expects URL in the form of api/{controller}/{id}, to override this default routing. you can set routing with any of below two ways.

**First option:**

Add below route registration in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Decorate your action method with HttpGet and parameters as below

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage ReadMyData(string param1,
                        string param2, string param3)

 {

// your code here

}
```

for calling above method url will be like below

http://localhost:[yourport]/api/MyData/ReadMyData?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

**Second option**
Add route prefix to Controller class and Decorate your action method with HttpGet as below. 
In this case no need change any  WebApiConfig.cs. It can have default routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{controller}/{action}")]
public class MyDataController : ApiController
{

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage ReadMyData(string param1,
                        string param2, string param3)

{

// your code here

}

}
```

for calling above method url will be like below

http://localhost:[yourport]/api/MyData/ReadMyData?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

Comment: I like the second option very much. Could you also show me how to use it in VB.net? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

In case you're using **ASP.NET 5** with **ASP.NET MVC 6**, most of these answers simply won't work because you'll normally let MVC create the appropriate route collection for you (using the default RESTful conventions), meaning that you won't find any `Routes.MapRoute()` call to edit at will.

The `ConfigureServices()` method invoked by the `Startup.cs` file will register MVC with the Dependency Injection framework built into ASP.NET 5: that way, when you call `ApplicationBuilder.UseMvc()` later in that class, the MVC framework will automatically add these default routes to your app. We can take a look of what happens behind the hood by looking at the `UseMvc()` method implementation within the framework source code:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMvc(
    [NotNull] this IApplicationBuilder app,
    [NotNull] Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
{
    // Verify if AddMvc was done before calling UseMvc
    // We use the MvcMarkerService to make sure if all the services were added.
    MvcServicesHelper.ThrowIfMvcNotRegistered(app.ApplicationServices);

    var routes = new RouteBuilder
    {
        DefaultHandler = new MvcRouteHandler(),
        ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices
    };

    configureRoutes(routes);

    // Adding the attribute route comes after running the user-code because
    // we want to respect any changes to the DefaultHandler.
    routes.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(
        routes.DefaultHandler,
        app.ApplicationServices));

    return app.UseRouter(routes.Build());
}
```

The good thing about this is that the framework now handles all the hard work, iterating through all the Controller's Actions and setting up their default routes, thus saving you some redundant work.

The bad thing is, there's little or no documentation about how you could add your own routes. Luckily enough, you can easily do that by using either a **Convention-Based** and/or an **Attribute-Based** approach (aka *Attribute Routing*).

**Convention-Based**

In your Startup.cs class, replace this:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

with this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // Route Sample A
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "RouteSampleA",
                    template: "MyOwnGet",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Items", action = "Get" }
                );
                // Route Sample B
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "RouteSampleB",
                    template: "MyOwnPost",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Items", action = "Post" }
                );
            });
```

**Attribute-Based**

A great thing about MVC6 is that you can also define routes on a per-controller basis by decorating either the `Controller` class and/or the `Action` methods with the appropriate `RouteAttribute` and/or `HttpGet` / `HttpPost` template parameters, such as the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/items
        [HttpGet()]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return GetLatestItems();
        }

        // GET: api/items/5
        [HttpGet("{num}")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get(int num)
        {
            return GetLatestItems(5);
        }       

        // GET: api/items/GetLatestItems
        [HttpGet("GetLatestItems")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetLatestItems()
        {
            return GetLatestItems(5);
        }

        // GET api/items/GetLatestItems/5
        [HttpGet("GetLatestItems/{num}")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetLatestItems(int num)
        {
            return new string[] { "test", "test2" };
        }

        // POST: /api/items/PostSomething
        [HttpPost("PostSomething")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string someData)
        {
            return Content("OK, got it!");
        }
    }
}
```

This controller will handle the following requests:

```
 [GET] api/items
 [GET] api/items/5
 [GET] api/items/GetLatestItems
 [GET] api/items/GetLatestItems/5
 [POST] api/items/PostSomething
```

Also notice that if you use the two approaches togheter, Attribute-based routes (when defined) would override Convention-based ones, and both of them would override the default routes defined by `UseMvc()`.

For more info, you can also [read the following post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/custom-routing-method-names-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/) on my blog.

Comment: This is perfect! None of the other answers actually did what I needed to. But you saved me :)

Comment: Is there a way to use a pre-defined model as a second parameter? For example, when I'm patching a certain user like this:   `public IActionResult Patch(int id, [FromQuery] Person person)`,  **all the incoming properties are null!**

Answer (score 9):

See this article for a longer discussion of named actions. It also shows that you can use the [HttpGet] attribute instead of prefixing the action name with "get".

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Web APi 2 and later versions support a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As the name implies, attribute routing uses attributes to define routes. Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web API. For example, you can easily create URIs that describe hierarchies of resources.

For example:

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

Will perfect and you don't need any extra code for example in WebApiConfig.cs.
Just you have to be sure web api routing is enabled or not in WebApiConfig.cs , if not you can activate like below:

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

You don't have to do something more or change something in WebApiConfig.cs. For more details you can have a look [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your WebAPIConfig.cs as bellow

```
Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Then implement your API as bellow

```
    // GET: api/Controller_Name/Show/1
    [ActionName("Show")]
    [HttpGet]
    public EventPlanner Id(int id){}
```