# Passing different type of argument to ApiController in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The below link shows how to creat ApiController.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

So how we can create a new method in controller with different paramaeter.

Something like this.

```
public bool SaveIttoDB(string name, string email, DateTime dob, int id)
{
    // code here
}
```

How we can access this method using URL?

Can anubody help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The URL for that type of action (assuming it's a `HttpGet`) would look like

```
http://domain/controller/SaveItToDb/name?email=value&dob=value&id=value
```

Or

```
http://domain/controller/SaveItToDb?name=value&email=value&dob=value&id=value
```

Comment: James, is the url is correct??? Don't we need to pass the value for name also???  http: //domain/controller/SaveItToDb?name=value&email=value&dob=value&id=value Is this correct url???

Comment: @PaRsH the value for `name` *is* being passed - in both URLs.

Comment: I don't think this would work for a WebApi controller since it expects the method names to start woth Get or Post? Unless you configure it otherwise, ofcourse

Comment: Argumentation for my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569270/custom-method-names-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: We dont have any post method in our controlle. We have to name the Action something like GetSaveItIoDB isn't it?

Comment: @JordyLangen I was focusing more on the actual question "*How can we access this method using URL?*" - I was assuming the OP had their route configured.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

Note, I'm converting a POST action to a GET action for demonstration purposes.

```
public bool GetSaveItToDB(string name, string email, DateTime dob, int id)
{
    // code here
}
```

You would call it using this url:

```
http://localhost/api/MyWebApiControllerName?name=John&email=john@doe.com&dpob=2012-13-05&id=1
```

It would normally be a POST:

```
public bool PostItToDB(string name, string email, DateTime dob, int id)
{
    // code here
}
```

You would then provide the parameters as POST parameters.