# WebApi conflict calling to functions, it's ignoring the function names

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have created a simple `ApiController` whit 3 functions.

- get() // Get all
- get(int id) // Get by id
- getFirst() // get the firsts in the list

I have 2 scenarios and I'll appreciate a lot a proper explanation.

- 1: If I implement only the `get()` and `get(int id)` it's working perfect when I call to `api/controller/{id}` (id optional)
- 2: When I have the 3 functions when I try to access to `api/controller/function/{id}` (id optional) it's not working. Only works the function to get by id. you can see the error I'm getting below.

  The request is invalid.
  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Practica.Models.Person GetById(Int32)' in 'Practica.Controllers.PersonController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Api Class:

public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        private Person[] listPerson;

```
    public PersonController() {
        listPerson = new Person[3];
        listPerson[0] = new Person { 
            id = 1,
            firstName = "test",
            lastName = "test",
            email = "test@gmail.com",
            age = 26
        };
        listPerson[1] = new Person
        {
            id = 2,
            firstName = "test",
            lastName = "test",
            email = "test@gmail.com",
            age = 26
        };
        listPerson[2] = new Person
        {
            id = 3,
            firstName = "test",
            lastName = "test",
            email = "test@gmail.com",
            age = 26
        };
    }

    public Person GetById(int id) {
        try
        {
            var person = this.listPerson.Where(p => p.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (person != null)
            {
                return person;
            }
            else {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    public Person[] Get()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.listPerson != null)
            {
                return this.listPerson;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    public Person GetFirst()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.listPerson != null)
            {
                return this.listPerson.Where(x=>x.Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

It's like the `ApiController` only recognize the get and the get?id, so someone can explain me why and how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: you can use route attribute on each function

Comment: what you mean exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569270/custom-method-names-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: I mean attribute routing by this way you can specify  different name to each function inside the controller http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @Prashant if you want publish an answer and I'll give you the points. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom method naming is asp.net web api.

By default the route configurations follows RESTful Conventions of GET,POST,PUT,Delete.

[Custom method names in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569270/custom-method-names-in-asp-net-web-api)

go through this post it will solve your problem.

Should work using the code below, just adding {action}

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```