# Calling custom methods in API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I added a method in my web api controller:

```
public String GetpeopleInFamily(string familyId)
```

I followed some examples from this question:
[Custom method names in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569270/custom-method-names-in-asp-net-web-api)

I updated my RouteConfig.cs file based off of what I read above:
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



        routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
        routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
        routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithActionAndId", "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
        routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("Get") });
        routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("Post") });
    }
```

But I'm still getting a 404 when calling the method:

**Request   GET /api/people/GetpeopleInFamily/101 HTTP/1.1**

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:17438/api/people/GetpeopleInFamily/101
>   '.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'people'
>   that matches the request."}

What do I need to do to get this to work?  As well as,  is this best practice to add custom methods that return a more complicated data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `familyId` is not mapped in the route. So you can create a new Mapping wich adds familyId to the id mapping or rewrite the parameter of `GetPeopleInFamily` to `id`.

Rewrite:

```
public string GetPeopleInFamily(string id)
```

Create new route: When you create a new route be sure that you remove the mapping with the `id` otherwise it won't work.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithActionAndFamilyId", "Api/{controller}/{action}/{familyId}", new { familyId = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { familyId = @"\d+" });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure your web API route to accept a familyId parameter.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "newont",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{familyId}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Controllername", familyId= "familyId", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }}
            );
```