# Why is my Web Api 2 Post method not hit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my apicontroller I have 2 methods which can handle Post requests:

```
public WatchListItemDTO Post(MovieDto movie)
{
    //do smt..
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("MarkMovieAsWatched/{id}")]
public void MarkMovieAsWatched(int id)
{
    // do smt..
}
```

The controller has prefix attribute: `[RoutePrefix("api/DownloadList")]`. When I make a (post) request to `http://localhost:4229/api/DownloadList/MarkMovieAsWatched/`it hits my `Post` method. The request also contains an object: `{id: 12}`.

My `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
    // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
    config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
}
```

Could someone explaint to me why the method `MarkMovieAsWatched` is not hit? And how to solve this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9569381/1558122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your route requires an id as part of the route.

Try changing your attribute to:

```
[Route("MarkMovieAsWatched/{id?}")]
```

That way if you don't pass the id as part of the path, the route will still be a valid match.