# Accessing the query string in MVC 6 Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, query-string, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a Get() function in a MVC 6 (Asp .Net 5) Web Api to pass a configuration option as a query string. Here are the two functions that I already have:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Project> GetAll()
{
    //This is called by http://localhost:53700/api/Project
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Project Get(int id)
{
    //This is called by http://localhost:53700/api/Project/4
}

[HttpGet()]
public dynamic Get([FromQuery] string withUser)
{
    //This doesn't work with http://localhost:53700/api/Project?withUser=true
    //Call routes to first function 'public IEnumerable<Project> GetAll()
}
```

I've tried several different ways to configure the routing, but MVC 6 is light on documentation. What I really need is a way to pass some configuration options to the list of Projects for sorting, custom filtering etc.

Comment: did you try [FromUri] attribute instead of [FromQuery]? in your last method.

Comment: [FromUri] is not an option. The only options are From+ [Body,Form,Header,Query,Route,Services].

Comment: bootRom and @Prashant  are correct - This changed from MVC5 to MVC6.  That was my problem.

Comment: My first question is why are you passing a bool as a string? Second is, you have two of the same items methods, and its totally fine for you to change "GetAll" to just be a "Get."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two `[HttpGet]`s with the same `template` in a single controller. I'm using asp.net5-beta7 and in my case it even throws the following exception:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.AmbiguousActionException
>   Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

The reason for this is that `[From*]` attributes are meant for binding, not routing.

The following code should work for you:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public dynamic Get([FromQuery] string withUser)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(withUser))
        {
            return new string[] { "project1", "project2" };
        }
        else
        {
            return "hello " + withUser;
        }
    }
```

Also consider using `Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.IRouteBuilder.MapRoute()` instead of attribute routing. It may give you more freedom defining the routes.

Comment: Yes, that works. I also came across the answer by trial and error, but I didn't understand why it worked. I agree using `IRouteBuilder.MapRoute()` is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the query string is very doable by using either the RESTful routing conventions (enforced by ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 by default) or by defining custom routes, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35396995/1233379).

Here's quick example using custom, *attribute-based* routes:

```
[HttpGet("GetLatestItems/{num}")]
public IEnumerable<string> GetLatestItems(int num)
{
    return new string[] { "test", "test2" };
}
```

For more info about custom routing, read [the following article](http://www.ryadel.com/en/custom-routing-method-names-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/) on my blog.