# Web Api - Swagger documentation error 500

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

When I access to the swagger url: `http://localhost:28483/swagger/ui/index`, it generates this error:

```
500 : undefined http://localhost:28483/swagger/docs/v1
```

Any ideas?

UPDATED:
See this detail error in firebug:

```
Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations
 with path 'api/BimModel' and method 'GET'. See the config setting - \"ResolveConflictingActions\" for
 a potential workaround
```

Comment: what's error you got?

Comment: @CuongLe: That's everything I got in the browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Swagger might be considering two actions as one operation (like in the case of this common scenario)...

```
GET api/Products
GET api/Products/{id}
```

It seems you can use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to fix this and use these attributes above your actions so swagger will recognize them separately.

```
[Route("api/Products")]

[Route("api/Products/{id:guid}")]
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried enable this in you swagger config?

```
c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
```

Comment: While this probably resolves the error, the other actions won't show up then in swagger.

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, it got two different GET operations and it is disallowed by Swagger. 
I suggest to either have only single GET operation for each controller or [modify the router in WebApiConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12185229/2491685)

Comment: Unfortunately modification of the router in ApiConfig does not helps. Still got `Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path...`. It looks like I have to create new controller for each get method or is there any other way how to force swagger to cooperate (some attributes,...)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when mixing attribute routing with default routes.
When I removed the default route the problem went away. The downside is, without the default route defined, I had to add attribute routing to all my controllers.

So from my WebApiConfig I removed:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And added attribute routing to my controller:

```cs
[Route("Session")] // Added this attribute
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
...    
[Route("Session/{id}")] // Added this attribute
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
```

In reality I use a `[RoutePrefix("Session")]` on my Controller and use `[Route("")]` on my methods, but the result should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error due to the parameter names not matching between the Attribute Routing statement and the method signature.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(string deviceNumber){
...
```

After changing "{id}" to "{deviceNumber}" it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error resulted from a duplicate http attribute:

```
[HttpPost("PostCustomer")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostCustomer([FromBody] Customer cust)
```

We were in the process of creating a new version of the endpoint, so I copied and pasted the old method, renaming the function name and forgot to rename the attribute:

```
[HttpPost("PostCustomer")] // Duplicate attribute maps to above method
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewCustomer([FromBody] Customer2 cust)
```

Once the second attribute was renamed to the new method, Swagger was fine again.

Answer (score -1):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please use English, as hardly anybody will be able to understand your answer. The idea of this site is that one person asks a question, another person answers it and the solution for the problem in question is documented for *everybody* with the same problem. So, if only a fraction of people understand your answer, it is kind of a waste ;)