# ASP.Net MVC 4 API custom method name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem that I want to call a MVC Api method with a custom name.

I changed the WebApi.config as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569270/custom-method-names-in-asp-net-web-api)

```
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id="test" }
    );
```

and wrote a class

```
public class MissingCardBoxModelController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/missingcardboxmodel
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/missingcardboxmodel/5
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }

    public string GetTrackingNumber(string parcelLabelNumber) 
    {
        string trackingNumber = "some number";
        return trackingNumber;
    }

    // POST api/missingcardboxmodel
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/missingcardboxmodel/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/missingcardboxmodel/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

But I can't call the method via http://localhost:58528/api/MissingCardBoxModel/GetTrackingNumber/123456

I Get the message

> No action was found on the controller 'MissingCardBoxModel' that
>   matches the request.

Why can't I call the method ?

Comment: what web api version are you using?

Comment: Try changing `parcelLabelNumber` in your arguments to `id`.

Comment: I use the Webapi Controller v1

Comment: @BrendanGreen Okay that solved the problem. I see where the problem is. I thought that the variable name id is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your routes are configured to be these (default in the MVC solution template):

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

You should change `parcelLabelNumber` to id.

You can read more about routes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

By Default Web API allows Restful conventions that means it will auto map `GET, PUT, POST, DELETE` etc action names. if you look inside your `WebApiConfig` in routes it only allows the route below

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

which means it only allows

> `.../api/yourcontrollername/a parameter that will map to id`

.
you basically have 2 options, one to use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). or you can add a route to your custom method eg:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "custom",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{parcelLabelNumber}",
                defaults: new { parcelLabelNumber = "" }
            );
```

please also notice the parameter name here "parcelLabelNumber", you have to name your parameter same here as in your action. You should be able to reach this action at - http://localhost:23691/api/MissingCardBoxModel/GetTrackingNumber/1245

Also please have a look at Routing in [general](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions)